# django model field for sets of values

Tags: django

I have a django model called Product. I wish to have a set of values. Specifically, each product will have different sizes (say 500 mg, 1 g, bulk order; the specific sizes will be differ for each product), along with it, I should have corresponding cost. For example,

- 1g - $500;
- 5g - $1500;
- bulk order -ask for quote;

For another product, this could be:

- 100ml - $100;
- 200ml -$170;
- 1L -$1000;

I could use something like:

```
size1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price1 = models.DecimalField
size2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price2 = models.DecimalField
size3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price3 = models.DecimalField
```

Is there a better way of achieving this? Is there something like sets field? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Product(models.Model):
   .....
   .....


class Price(models.Model):
    prodcut = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, "Gram"),
    (2, "ML"),
    (3, "L"),
    )
    quanty_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
    quanty = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

Comment: Thanks. I probably did not explain well. I wish to have sets of three different quantities with three corresponding prices for each product. Not just one quantity type and one price.

Answer (score 1):

Create another model - Size:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    units = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This way you can create as many sizes as you want, sequence will indicate the order number of a Size object belonging to the product. If you want to just note about bulk order, then just fill the notes `notes = 'bulk order - ask for quote'` and skip units, value and price, those will be None by default.

Comment: Don't store monetary values ​​in a FloatField, use a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) for that. Also you might consider using [JsonField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) for unstructured values, it will a good choice, especially if you don't need to search for these parameters.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you probably even better store monetary values in Integer ( in cents), I just think that in this particular case you can use Float if there are no monetary transactions.